# Poor Video Playback - Low Frame Rate

Tags: video, video-player, vlc, codecs

I have pretty poor frame rate when playing .avi video files.

I tried VLC player, but I am still not satisfied because it is bad comparing to windows. I played some .rmvb (RealMedia) movie yesterday, and it was damn slow.

I use ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphic driver and default VLC setup.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: From my expirience, amd + linux = no go.

Comment: What's the system's overall load and performance?<br>
Can you open the system monitor and see?<br>
Sometimes Compiz eats all the CPU...
<br><br>
But if the CPU is fine I recommend X11 as the video output and disabling any hardware acceleration. You could also try SMplayer which has more video outputs available...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the video renderer in VLC? Also, i think there is a enable hardware decoding checkbox. Also, (at least when using mesa drivers from the optimized ppa) there might be a package that will allow nVidia VDPAU to work with ati cards. One more thing, if your really desperate, buy a Broadcom crystal hd.

Comment: Thanks. Change video renderer to what?

Comment: Um, honestly, I have no idea. I haven't used VLC in a while, but there are only like 7 options, right? Trial and error, I guess?

Comment: There are http://i.imgur.com/2Mcg2.png I don't see any difference, do I need to restart player between switches?

Comment: Based on my somewhat limited experience with graphic drivers, I say use GLX. And a player restart dosent hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have you compared the perfomance differences with using the free drivers and the ATI ones? When you use the free drivers, make sure you have "libgl1-mesa-dri", "libosmesa6", and "libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental" packages installed. For better results, add the ppa "ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers", "ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates", and install the "libg3dvl-mesa" package. Your card seems similar to mine at least in terms of age. I have a ATI Radeon Xpress 1150 (RS480M), and these free drivers work for me.

Comment: Thanks. Installed them all, but still same results. Note: when I open "additional drivers" still same list http://i.imgur.com/fNVRS.png Should I activate them somehow?

Comment: Well, that's as much as I can be of help. Sorry. On a side note, post release updates are safe and recommended to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is quite problematic on some formats. What gives me very good results playing .avi files is Smplayer. You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center or from Synaptic (it depends on your preferences).